# birt integration for grails Error Failed to resolve dependencies

Tags: grails, integration, birt

is there any working example around I can see? I downloaded this
http://www.it-jw.com/grails/birt-report-test_0.5.zip from here http://grails.org/plugin/birt-report

but keeps giving me error

> "Error Failed to resolve dependencies "

. When I browse http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ it says :

> Browsing for this directory has been disabled. View this directory's
>   contents on http://search.maven.org instead. Find out more about The
>   Central Repository.

I tried adding all jars manually in lib/classpath but did not work. I have never done birt integration before. A basic tutorial aside form the link above would be great. Or at least give me idea how I can run that project as I have already exhausted what I can. thanks

Comment: are you using eclipse? make sure you install the birt plugin for eclipse too.

Comment: yes I am using eclipse. there is birt plugin installed.

Comment: I recently installed the birt plugin but was not facing such error I will help you when you reach the errors I was facing lol but when are you gettting this error? Are you sure it is because of the birt plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run this by modifying the buildConfig.groovy file.

```
dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.5'

        compile 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.core.runtime:3.10.0.v20140318-2214'

        compile('org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.birt.runtime:4.4.1') {
         excludes 'flute', 'eclipse.core.runtime', 'xmlbeans'

        }
        runtime 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.185'
    }

//commented out all the plugins{}
```